# Limit to 1 only if return multiple in if statement flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

Let say i have a list of array as given

```
Array listarray = ['1','2','3','3','3','4','5','6','6','7','8']

for (int i = 0; i<listarray.length; i++){
 if(listarray[i] == '3'){
   return 'this is three';
 }else if (listarray[i] == '6'){
   return 'this is six';
 }
}
```

it will return as

```
this is threethis is threethis is threethis is sixthis is six
```

I would like to know if there's a way for me to return the first one only or maybe limit it to 1 return only?

so that it will be something like

```
this id threethis is six
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: there is no type *Array* in dart, there is *List* though.

You can remove duplicates by converting list to set:

```dart
var listarray = ['1','2','3','3','3','4','5','6','6','7','8'];
listarray = listarray.toSet().toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, the other answers have given the right approach of using `sets`. My approach is little bit different, keeping the **the above conditions in mind, that is, to search for minimum possible elements**

To do that, my algorithm is:

```
1. take two bools, which will keep a track on the items, in this case, for element 6 and 3
2. If conditions check for the item == the element and if the bool is false
3. If satisfies, make the bool return true, and print the item
```

**Please note:** I am using `print`, you can use your `return`, in place of print in the code

```
void main() {
  bool _threeFound = false;
  bool _sixFound = false;
  
  List<String> listarray = ['1','2','3','3','3','4','5','6','6','7','8'];
  
  for(var item in listarray){
    // it won't come unless satisfies the condition
    // and it will come only once
    if(item == '3' && _threeFound == false){
      _threeFound = true;
      print('this is three');
    }else if(item == '6' && _sixFound == false){
      _sixFound = true;
      print('this is six');
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
this is three
this is six
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  var arr = ['1','2','3','3','3','4','5','6','6','7','8'];
  
  //make values unique
  var uniqueValues = LinkedHashSet.from(arr);
  
  //transform input values to output values
  var mappedValues = uniqueValues.map((item){
    if(item == '3'){
      return 'this is three';
    } else if (item == '6'){
      return 'this is six';
    }
  }).toList();
  
  //remove null value from output
  mappedValues.removeWhere((value) => value == null);
    
  print(mappedValues);
  
}
```